# Is it possible to describe a property who's value must always be greater than that of another property?

Tags: jsonschema

I have a requirement where the value of one property must always be greater than the value of a different property.

If propertyOne is 30 then propertyTwo must be at least 31 for example.

Pseudo code for what I want:

```
"propertyOne": {
    "type": "integer",
    "minimum": 1 + <value of whatever propertyTwo is>
},
```

I have not found any examples of how to do this- is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by the pure JSON schema standard. The ajv implementation for JavaScript does support the [$data](https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/51) extension to access any value using a JSONPointer in the instance but you can't use expressions. But for your simple example, it would be sufficient.